# Parser Error On Remix Solidity ERC20 Smart Contract Token

Tags: solidity, remix

This Is My First ERC20 Smart Contract Token. I Am Trying To Compile It Using Solidity 0.5.0. Plz Need Your Help Guys.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    contract TusharCoin {

  uint256 public totalSupply;  
  string public name;  
  string public symbol;  
  uint32 public decimals; 

    constructor () public {
  symbol  = "TUSHAR";  
  name = "TusharCoin";  
  decimals = 5;  
  totalSupply = 100000000000;
    }

    constructor() public { 
  owner = msg.sender;  
  balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, totalSupply);  
 }
```

```
Error- Function, Variable, Struct Or Modifier Declaration Expected. 

emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, totalSupply); 
^--^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should implement the functionality you tried to implement in the question

```java
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TusharCoin {

  uint256 public totalSupply;  
  string public name;  
  string public symbol;  
  uint32 public decimals;
  address public owner;

  mapping(address => uint256 ) balances;

  event Transfer(address to, uint256 amount);

  constructor () public {
    symbol  = "TUSHAR";  
    name = "TusharCoin";  
    decimals = 5;  
    totalSupply = 100000000000;
    owner = msg.sender;  
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
 }
```

But to implement an ERC20 token, you have to implement all the functions described in the interface [standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20). You can have a look at openzeppelin implementation [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20).

Comment: See the OpenZeppelin documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

Alternatively you could look at creating ERC777 tokens (no need to do approve and transferFrom in two separate transactions). See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC777